# Proving where a function is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x) = x|x|$ and $g(x) = |x-1| + |x+1|$ for what values of $x$ are these two functions differentiable?

I tried using the difference quotient for these two functions but I couldn't exactly get it, I'm also not even sure what I would state to prove where these functions are differentiable. I know that $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere, and that $g(x)$ has corners at$-1,1$ so it is not differentiable at those two values but I'm not exactly sure how to PROVE this.

Comment: For example, for $f$, it is clear (why?) that it is differentiable at all $x \neq 0$. So you only need to check, using the difference quotient, at $x=0$.

Comment: Start by using basic principles you should know. If two functions are differentiable at a point, both their product and sum are differentiable at that point. Right away that should tell you where to look at where these functions are NOT differentiable. Namely, $0$ for $f$ and $-1$,$1$ for $g$. From there, I would just use the definition of the derivative via limits. You should have the same problems with left and right hand limits as you would for the absolute value function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On intervals where the expressions in absolute value bars don't change sign, these functions are polynomials. Polynomials are everywhere differentiable. So, these functions are differentiable *at least* everywhere but at the aforementioned points. You need only check those finitely many points to see what happens there, and those are simple limits of difference quotients.

For example, $f(x)=-x^2$ on $(-\infty,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi$ is differentiable at $x_0$ then $\phi'(x_0) = \lim_{h \to 0} {\phi(x_0+h)-\phi(x_0) \over h}$.

To show that $g$ is not differentiable at $\pm 1$, take the limit above with $h>0$ and $h<0$. This will give different answers, from which it follows that
the limit above does not exist and hence $g$ is not differentiable at those points.

It should be clear that $f$ is differentiable for $x \ne 0$. For $x=0$, note
that $|{f(h)-f(0) \over h}| \le |h|$, from which it follows that $f$ is
differentiable at $x=0$ with derivative $0$.